# How to get method on an Ocx in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ocx

So this is a both a general and very specific question:
My client has a vb6 project migrating to vb.net as does not want to upgrade to a new component.
This is with respect to VSPrinter.
I can import the lib no problems and it works.
Code:
Imports VSPrinter8Lib
And then
Dim VS As New VSPrinter
With VS
etc..
End With
I can access all properties and all good.
But…
When it fires a NewPage() I have no way of trapping that method.
How do I do that?
If I create a form and drop the ocx on it I can get that
Private Sub VS_NewPage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VS.NewPageEvent
MsgBox("J")
End Sub
But then I can’t use VS.Picture = VS.LoadPicture(etc) to bring in an image.

I think I am missing how to load an ocx library an get at the methods programmatically.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just add the event handler in code, or am I missing something?  And what does VSPrinter do the the native printer functionality not?

Comment: OK figured out. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps post your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: You need to create a form, add VsPrinter as an ocx component, then do this:

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form, add `VsPrinter` as an OCX component, then do this:

```
.Picture = .get_LoadPicture(your picture)
```

This is different than VB6 `LoadPicture`. You also need to pass `ByRef` your initial call to any sub call. So, as an example, on your form load, if you want to call a routine that loads a picture you first

```
Import AxVSPrinter8Lib
```

and then create a call `GetCoLogo(Me.VS)` to

```
Private Shared Sub GetCoLogo(ByRef VS As AxVSPrinter)
```